# How to add an item to the menu Intellij IDEA (IDEA plugin)

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

For the first time in my life I am developing a plugin for IDEA. Already almost fully implemented all the functionality. Now you need to add an item to the file-> settings menu. How can I do that? In the documentation I did not find anything like this.

Answer (score 2):

Here the page you need: [Creating an action](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/creating_an_action.html) that [describes](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/creating_an_action.html#registering-actions) that:

> Once you have defined an action or a system of actions, you must register them to specify the menu items or toolbar buttons associated with actions. You can register actions in one of the following ways:
>
> - Register actions in the `<actions>` section of the plugin.xml file.
> - Register actions from Java code.